# Draw tiled images in CGContext with a scale transformation gives precision errors

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I want to draw tiled images and then transform them by using the usual panning and zooming gestures. The problem that brings me here is that, whenever I have a scaling transformation of a large number of decimal places, a thin line of pixels (1 or 2) appears in the middle of the tiles. I managed to isolate the problem like this:

```
CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

CGContextSetFillColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGColorGetComponents([UIColor redColor].CGColor));
CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect);//rect from drawRect:

float scale = 0.7;
CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), scale, scale);
CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100), testImage);
CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(150, 50, 100, 100), testImage);
CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
```

With a 0.7 scale, the two images appear correctly tiled:
[image: 0.7 scale]

With a 0.777777 scale (changing line 6 to "float scale = 0.777777;"), the visual artifact appears:

[image: 0.777777 scale]

Is there any way to avoid this problem? This happens with CGImage, CGLayer and primitive forms such as a rectangle. It also happens on MacOSx.

Thanks for the help!

edit: Added that this also happens with a primitive form, like CGContextFillRect

edit2: It also happens on MacOSx!

Comment: What if instead of using "float", you use "CGFloat"?  Edit: nevermind, this shouldn't matter.

Comment: Comments like "Android does this fine, (implying why is iOS so sucky!) won't win you many friends here :-)

Comment: removed the Android reference, didn't meant to imply anything, just wanted to give as much information as possible about what I have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quartz has a floating point coordinate system, so scaling may result in values that are not on pixel boundaries, resulting in visible antialiasing at the edges. If you don't want that, you have two options:

1. Adjust your scale factor so that all your scaled coordinates are integral. This may not always be possible, especially if you're drawing lots of things.
2. Disable anti-aliasing for your graphics context using `CGContextSetShouldAntialias(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), false);`. This will result in crisp pixel boundaries, but anything but straight lines might not look very good.

Comment: It was the antialias!!! Thanks!! I had to tried to enable anti aliasing before, thought it was disabled by default...

Comment: And looking back now, I was always intrigued as to why the line was not completely red, it was a blended red with white... I guess it was the algorithm who blended the red with last pixels of the image on the first pass, issuing that line on the border, it had nothing to with the second image.

Answer (score 0):

When all is said and done, iOS is dealing with discrete pixels on integer boundaries. When your frames are reduced 0.7, the 50 is reduced to 35, right on a pixel boundary. At 0.777777 it is not - so iOS adapts and moves/shrinks/blends whatever.

You really have two choices. If you want to use scaling of the context, then round the desired value up or down so that it results in integral scaled frame values (your code shows 50 as the  standard multiplication value.)

Otherwise, you can not scale the context, but scale the content one by one, and use CGIntegralRect to round all dimensions up or down as needed.

EDIT: If my suspicion is right, there is yet another option for you. Lets say you want a scale factor of .77777 and a frame of 50,50,100,100. You take the 50, multiply it by the scale, then round the return value up or down. Then you recompute the new frame by using that value divided by 0.7777 to get some fractional value, that when scaled by 0.7777 returns an integer. Quartz is really good at figuring out that you mean an integral value, so small rounding errors are ignored. I'd bet anything this will work just fine for you.

Comment: Shouldn't the rounding of integers yield the same result in the right boundary of the first image, and on the left boundary of the second image? Since both are calculated from a 100*scale calculation, the loss of precision should still be overlapping. And it is quite difficult for me to receive the scaling, since my tiled drawing engine receives a context with a preset transformation.

Comment: We can argue all day WHAT the proper behavior is, what I'm trying to say is what it probably is. It's extremely inefficient for apple to figure out what to draw in some pixel when it has to average four pixels. I suspect they don't do that, and as a result the image is aligned at least on some dimensions on integral values. Startup "Pixie" and look closely at the gap and see what's there - bet is a thin one pixel line of red.

Comment: I tested in a MacOSx app and the same thing happens, I was hoping that it was related to the 1 unit 2 pixels change with the retina displays in iOS. Will try your edit as soon as I can. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: I tried your editted solution, and it didn't work. I assume you meant doing something like this on all rectangle values:
floorf(value*scale)/scale;
In the meantime, "omz" solved it for me, it was the anti aliasing that was making the line!